# BundleURL error when trying to generate pre-bundled file

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-native

When trying to build ios client in `react-native`, I modified part of `AppDelegate.m` file as shown below (i.e., replaced option 1 with option 2):

```
// OPTION 1
  // Load from development server. Start the server from the repository root:
  //
  // $ npm start
  //
  // To run on device, change `localhost` to the IP address of your computer, and make sure your computer and
  // iOS device are on the same Wi-Fi network.
  //jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle"];

  // OPTION 2
  // Load from pre-bundled file on disk. To re-generate the static bundle, run
  //
  // $ curl http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle -o main.jsbundle
  //
  // and uncomment the next following line
  jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

I downloaded `main.jsbundle` to the `iOS` folder where `AppDelegate.m` is.

```
$ ls iOS
AppDelegate.h   Base.lproj      Info.plist      main.m
AppDelegate.m   Images.xcassets main.jsbundle
```

But, if I do the build again in XCode and run it in `ios simulator`, it pauses in `main.m` with the following error:

> 2015-03-31 12:46:28.877 AwesomeProject[26849:1320518] *** Assertion
>   failure in -[RCTRootView initWithBundleURL:moduleName:launchOptions:],
>   /Users/yourname/scripts/code/startup/reactnative/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTRootView.m:82
>   2015-03-31 12:46:28.883 AwesomeProject[26849:1320518] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: 'A bundleURL is required to create an RCTRootView'

So, it seems to be complaining about `bundleURL`. I will appreciate help with identifying what the issue is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the file to the project.
To do so, you need to **right-click on the project name** and select **"Add files to MyProject…"**. Then choose the *main.jsbundle*.

Then build your project and it should work.

See: [How to build React Native App for iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29374410/how-to-build-react-native-app-for-iphone/29374411#29374411)

Comment: Thank you! It was such a head scratcher about what I missed.