# How to build React Native App for iPhone?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

On the iPhone simulator everything works fine. When building the App for the iPhone i get the error:

> A bundleURL is required to create an RCTRootView

In the **AppDelegate.m** i uncomment the following line;

```
jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

And downloaded the prebuild main.jsbundle to the iOS folder in the project root:

```
curl http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle -o main.jsbundle
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this inside an AppDelegate.swift - doesn't seem to work - Asked here also: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/240

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I forgot to add the file to the project.

You need to **right-click on the project name** and select **"Add files to MyProject…"**. Then choose the ***main.jsbundle***. Build the project and it should work.

Comment: Yeah, or just download the main.jsbundle to the iOS folder inside the root directory of the app instead of the root directory itself.